# Rails 5 upgrade enum value changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, enumeration, state-machine

I am new to ROR and I am trying to upgrade a Rails application from 4.2 to 5.2
Ruby Version: 2.3

I have a model named 'Recommendation'

The association inside of it is like this

```
class Recommendation < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :state, class_name: 'WorkflowState', foreign_key: :workflow_state_id
```

The WorkflowState is a model and contains a list of possible state

```
class WorkflowState < ApplicationRecord

WORKFLOW_STATES = ['DRAFT',
                     'PENDING_APPROVAL',
                     'APPROVED']

  def self.state_enums
    hash = {}
    WorkflowState.distinct.each do |state|
      hash[state.to_sym] = state.id
    end
    hash
  end
```

There is also a Recommendation State Machine which match the workflow state id with the enum value

```
module RecommendationStateMachine
  # state setting
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.send(:include, AASM)

    klass.enum workflow_state_id: WorkflowState.state_enums

    # States
    klass.aasm column: :workflow_state_id, enum: true do
      state :draft, initial: true
      state :pending_approval
      state :approved
```

Before upgrade, through rails console

```
r = Recommendation.first
=> #<Recommendation id: 120463,  workflow_state_id: 3>
```

But after upgrade, through rails console

```
r = Recommendation.first
=> #<Recommendation id: 120463,  workflow_state_id: "apprvoed">
```

Because of this change, the belongs_to breaks since the workflow_state_id doesn't match with the id from WorkflowState table.

I cannot get how this change can happen from upgrading. Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you paste the db schema for `Recommendation` and `WorkflowState`? You can find them in `db/schema.rb` ... Just find the entries where it says `create_table recommendations` and `create_table workflow_states`

Comment: `workflow_state_id: "apprvoed"` is not correct. There are also quite a few problem with this approach. `WorkflowState.distinct.each` relies on the records in the database having the same exact ordering as the constant in the model and any changes to the database table would break it. If you want to use a normalization table for this you want to store a bitmask or a string and not rely on the autoincremented id.

Answer (score 1):

There is a change in the `ActiveRecord::Enum` from Rails 5.0.0. Which is the reason for displaying the enum value in the string format rather than the integer value.   Below is the commit link which explains this [link](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/c51f9b61ce1e167f5f58f07441adcfa117694301)